# Error in Angular with HTTPparams 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and FastAPI

Tags: angular, rest, fastapi, http-status-code-422, http-parameters

I have this url in backend and need pass c1 like a parameter, c1 is only an example,
this method enable or disable an user and give back an "ok"

http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/enable_disable_account?name=c1

the value is taken from a button

```html
<div *ngFor='let userInfo of users'>
 <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">username -> {{userInfo["username"]}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">email -> {{userInfo["email"]}}</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">enable/disable -> {{userInfo["enable"]}}</li>
 </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="setValor(userInfo['username'])">Enable/Disable</button>   
</div>
```

The method of the component to managment that click event

```js
    setValor(username): void {
    console.log("click")
    this.adminServ.updateStateUser(username)
    .subscribe(data => {
      
      console.log(data)
    },
    err => {
      console.log("error")
      console.error(err)
    })
  }
```

And the method in the service

```js
    public updateStateUser(username): Observable<any> {
    let params = new HttpParams()
      .append('name', username)      
    return this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/enable_disable_account', params)
  }
```

and i have this error, what is the problem?
[image]

I copy here the method of the backend, i dont know if it's important to find the problem,
it's done with FastAPI

```py
@router.post("/enable_disable_account")
async def enable_disable_account(name: str, current_user: User =   Security(get_current_user, scopes=["admin"])):           
  result = await admin_db.enable_disable_account(name)
  if result:
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
                        content='ok')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/enable_disable_account', params)
```

this line is incorrect.

`Angular` http client `post` method second parameter is `body`, and third parameter is `options`.

when you want to set `query` and pass `params` you need to pass as third parameter. and also you must to send as a object not just `HttpParams`.
[Angular Http Client API reference](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post)

```js
this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/enable_disable_account',null ,{
params: params
})
```