# How to call POST API using body prams in angular [ raise 422 error (Unprocessable Entity)]

Tags: python, angular, fastapi, pydantic

I'm struggling to use Post API using FastAPI , Angular
while using HttpClient.post Function

the issue with receiving the prams in the backend FastAPI no seeing the prams
and raise 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

- Mybackend API CODE (FastAPI-Python):

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel
class UsersLoginRequest(BaseModel):
    username: str
    password: str


@users_router.post("/login")
def login(body: UsersLoginRequest):
    pass
```

- Start backend:

```py
Uvicorn running on http: //127.0.0.1:3101 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Started reloader process [36366] using WatchFiles
Started server process 363701
Waiting for application startup.
Application startup complete
```

- Call API using Postman cURL example:

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin"
}'
```

```py
# See trafic ... 

127.0.0.1:54336 - "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

try same API using angular frontend by calling this.http.post :

```js
import { HttpClient  ,HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

 constructor( private http:HttpClient )

signIn(): void
    { 
        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 
        let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('username', "admin")
        .append('password', "admin")
 
          debugger
        this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login',params   ,{ headers: headers }
        ).subscribe({ 
        error: (respose:any) => { 
            debugger
         },    // errorHandler 
        next: (respose:any) => {  
            debugger
        },     // nextHandler 
    })
 
}
```

backend trafic :

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:62969 - "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

try to change parameter place

```js
import { HttpClient  ,HttpHeaders, HttpParams} from '@angular/common/http';

 constructor(
        private http:HttpClient
    )

signIn(): void
    {

        const headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        
        let params = new HttpParams()
        .append('username', "admin")
        .append('password', "admin")
 
          debugger
        this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login',null   ,{ headers: headers, params: params }
        ).subscribe({ 
        error: (respose:any) => { 
            debugger
         },    // errorHandler 
        next: (respose:any) => {  
            debugger
        },     // nextHandler 
    })
 
}
```

backend trafic :

```py
INFO:     127.0.0.1:62969 - "POST /users/login HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

**I DON'T KNOW WHAT I MISSING !!!!**

I'm trying to receive body prams in python - FastAPI

for the record ::

I did try this slotion it didnt work

[Error in Angular with HTTPparams 422 (Unprocessable Entity) and FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69262116/error-in-angular-with-httpparams-422-unprocessable-entity-and-fastapi)

you can see the example above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to send the object instead of http params. For example:

```
    this.http.post('http://127.0.0.1:3101/users/login',{user: "foo", password: "bar"},{ headers: headers })
```

It could be you are sending an http form?

Comment: For the record, `HttpParams` is query parameters, so OP was posting to `/users/login?username=admin&password=admin`.